# vue transition group animation stuck

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a `<transition-group>` that used to work, but as soon as I began using `await` on a remote call in the component's `mounted()` hook, the `<transition-group>` stopped working. What happens is the transitioning elements in question get the `<transition-name>-enter-to` class but it never changes. Again, this only happens if I `await` that remote call in the component's `mounted` hook.

This works:

```
<transition-group name="file-list" appear>
  <li v-for="file in files" :key="file.id">
    <file :id="file.id"/>
  </li>
</transition-group>

...

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.remoteCallToGetFiles();
  }
}
```

But when I await the remote call, the `<file>` component gets the `file-list-enter-to` class and it never changes, it just gets stuck there:

```
<transition-group name="file-list" appear>
  <li v-for="file in files" :key="file.id">
    <file :id="file.id"/>
  </li>
</transition-group>

...

export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.remoteCallToGetFiles();
  }
}
```

Comment: If that's all the code to the `mounted` hook, you don't need to `await` the call.